# Using “though" in the middle of a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

> Adults can usually tell if a claim made in an advertising campaign is blatantly false, though, through comparison with prior knowledge and life experience.

This is the exact sentence I wrote in a test and my teacher marked the `though` as wrong. I had previously also written similar sentences and she said that `though` should only ever go at the end of a sentence. Is this correct?

Comment: I don't see an issue with "though", assuming this is building on context mentioned previously, like children not recognizing false advertising.

Comment: Yeah, that is the case

Comment: There is no requirement that "though" can only go at the end of a sentence.  If that was the basis of your teacher's issue, she is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Though" is a subordinating conjunctive word, contrasting the new thought about adults usually being able to identify a false advertising claim with previous sentences or ideas. IF there were previous sentences with which you were contrasting your statement about adults, then what you wrote is correct. But without any other sentences or ideas preceding yours, then using "though" is incorrect, as your new thought needs to be subordinate to a preceding thought. It is not the *placement* of the word "though" in the middle of the sentence that is incorrect.

Since you have not indicated if there was a preceding sentence, here is an example where your sentence would be used correctly:

> > Children and teenagers often naively believe the claims of TV advertisements. They can waste their parents' money buying products with the hope of experiencing exactly what they see in these ads. Adults can usually tell if a claim made in an advertising campaign is blatantly false, though, through comparison with prior knowledge and life experience.

However, to use the sentence as is -- with no prior sentences and ideas for contrast -- is incorrect.

To learn more about subordinating conjunctives, and see other examples of them within sentences, check out this page at [http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/conjunctions/subordinating-conjunctions.html](http://yourdictionary.com)

Comment: Wow, those sentences are great! Mine was `Even adults are not immune to psychological tricks and subliminal manipulation used in the advertising industry.` So the `though` is actually contrasting the next sentence, which is about children

Comment: Better use the conjunctive "though" with a preceding clause, and not one in the next sentence. Hope this info and the site is helpful.